# ASP.Net MVC How to pass an h2 tag value to Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i'm new in ASP.NET MVC and I want to pass an

value to controller in mvc, because I have the h2 tag with contenteditable and I can't put the name attribute to pass the value to the controller.

This is an example:

```
<h2 contenteditable="true">Hello World</h2>
```

when I edit the text, I want to pass the value to the controller

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You mean on submission of a form?

Comment: I fear you will ned a submit button and some javscript to stuff the current text of the h2 into a variable which will be post to an action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a hidden input tag to represent your editable H2.

```
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenH2" id="hiddenH2" value="">
```

Then on submit, set the hidden input value to the value of the h2. (*This code uses Jquery*).

```
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        val h2Value = $('h2').html();
        $('input[name="hiddenH2"]').val(h2Value);
        return true;
    });
});
```